# How can processes eliminate escape codes when its output is piped?

Tags: terminal, pipe, stdout, escape-characters

That's a pretty weird title but I'm having trouble articulating this question:

When I run `kitty --version` in my terminal it prints its version out to stdout, however the text is styled and colored:

[image]

In order to achieve this the process had to output ANSI escape codes to stdout, however I don't see them when I hexdump the output:

```
$ kitty --version | xxd -g 1 -c 10 -u
00000000: 6B 69 74 74 79 20 30 2E 31 39  kitty 0.19
0000000a: 2E 31 20 63 72 65 61 74 65 64  .1 created
00000014: 20 62 79 20 4B 6F 76 69 64 20   by Kovid 
0000001e: 47 6F 79 61 6C 0A              Goyal.
```

I'd expect to see at least a few escape characters and other ANSI sequences here but I don't. This leads me to believe that `kitty` is able to "predict" whether its output will appear in a terminal that can process the escape codes.

How is it able to do that? Or is it a feature of the terminal emulator perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `man isatty`, or https://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty

```
isatty - test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal
```

Comment: @bool3max if you wonder how `isatty()` actually determines if a file descriptor is a tty, (since, unlike with fifos, there are no special st_mode flags for ttys), is that `isatty()` is actually caling an ioctl like `TCGETS` or `TIOCGWINSZ` which is supposed to only works on ttys. If you wonder how `kitty` or other program determines if a tty supports *color escapes*, it that it's doing it in a very unreliable way, by looking for the value of the `TERM` envvar into some kind of incomplete and obsolete database (terminfo) or just going on and assuming that *any* terminal supports color escapes.

Comment: @user414777 Thank for you for the additional insight!!